# How to retrieve data using spring rest API in an insensitive case way?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, spring-data-jpa

I am making a Rest API with Spring Boot.
I have a method like this in my controller:

```java
    @GetMapping("/dead")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<DeadEntity>> getDeadByCountryRegion(@RequestParam(value = "country") String countryRegion) {
        List<DeadEntity> entity = serviceDead.findEntityByCountryRegion(countryRegion);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and my url looks like: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dead/?country=**Russia**

but I want to be able get data with this url too. http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dead/?country=**russia**

What should I do? Thanks.

**Entity**

```java
public class DeadEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String provinceState;
    private String countryRegion;
    private String lat;
    private String lon;
    private int latestTotalCases;
    private int diffFromPrevDay;

    public DeadEntity() {
    }

    public DeadEntity(Long id, String provinceState, String countryRegion, String lat, String lon, int latestTotalCases, int diffFromPrevDay ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.provinceState = provinceState;
        this.countryRegion = countryRegion;
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.latestTotalCases = latestTotalCases;
        this.diffFromPrevDay = diffFromPrevDay;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLatestTotalCases() {
        return latestTotalCases;
    }

    public void setLatestTotalCases(int latestTotalCases) {
        this.latestTotalCases = latestTotalCases;
    }

    public int getDiffFromPrevDay() {
        return diffFromPrevDay;
    }

    public void setDiffFromPrevDay(int diffFromPrevDay) {
        this.diffFromPrevDay = diffFromPrevDay;
    }

    public String getProvinceState() {
        return provinceState;
    }

    public void setProvinceState(String provinceState) {
        this.provinceState = provinceState;
    }

    public String getCountryRegion() {
        return countryRegion;
    }

    public void setCountryRegion(String countryRegion) {
        this.countryRegion = countryRegion;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    @JsonProperty("long")
    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }
}
```

**I get data from CSV remote file**

```java
 private void fillEntityProperties(Iterable<CSVRecord> newRecord, List<DeadEntity> newEntity) {
        for (CSVRecord record : newRecord) {
            DeadEntity locationStats = new DeadEntity();
            for (long j = 0; j <= newEntity.size(); j++)
                locationStats.setId(j);
            locationStats.setProvinceState(record.get("Province/State"));
            locationStats.setCountryRegion(record.get("Country/Region")); //The country name comes from remote data source in Uppercase mode
            locationStats.setLat(record.get("Lat"));
            locationStats.setLon(record.get("Long"));
            int latestCases = Integer.parseInt(record.get(record.size() - 1));
            int prevDayCases = Integer.parseInt(record.get(record.size() - 2));
            locationStats.setLatestTotalCases(latestCases);
            locationStats.setDiffFromPrevDay(latestCases - prevDayCases);
            newEntity.add(locationStats);
            saveDeadInDB(locationStats);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would chancing the argument help? You need to issue a different query. `findEntityByCountryRegionIgnoreCase` should be the name of your method on your dao .

Comment: Woow, really appreciated. I didn't even know that Spring Jpa provides that like this. I am newbie in spring :)))) I started 15 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For query parameters it is not your url the problem

```
 @GetMapping("/dead")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<List<DeadEntity>> getDeadByCountryRegion(@RequestParam(value = "country") String countryRegion) {
        List<DeadEntity> entity = serviceDead.findEntityByCountryRegion(countryRegion);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

> and my url looks like:
> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dead/?country=Russia
>
> but I want to be able get data with this url too.
> http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dead/?country=russia

It would be a problem if you wanted as url the http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dead/?**COUNTRY=russia**

So the value of the query parameter is not something the @RequestParam cares about.

However that could be handled on your DB level on how you make your queries, and there is something that you can do to make that case incensitive.

Declare in your JPA repository a method with name `findByCountryRegionIgnoreCase(countryRegion);`

instead of `findByCountryRegion(countryRegion)`

and fire that on your controller where you execute the `serviceDead.findEntityByCountryRegion(countryRegion);`

Edit: Corrected repository method names

Comment: Dear Boug thank you so much for you guidance. Exactly what I want.

Comment: @FaramarzAfzali please consider accepting answer if it has solved your problem